# Java implementation of complex formulas?

Tags: java, formula

Is this implementation of the following formula correct? I'm having a hard time implementing certain formula into java:

```
Formula (Original)
Y（x，y，t）=A*cos（w *（x，y）+ wt*t + FI;

Formula (Java)
float yPos = (float) (A* Math.cos((w * (y) + w *   (x)) + wt* t+ FI));
```

yPos is the y (up) position of a vector on a grid. And since the original formula appears to return a vector i simply applied it to y.

I have created a 3 dimensional grid that contains vertices. Each vertices position is changed in an update loop using a nested for loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
            float xPos = x;
            float yPos = 0;
            float zPos = y;               
            yPos += sineY(x, y, time); // Cant be consistant Waves

            waterVertexPos.set(xPos, yPos, zPos); //y is where z is
            vertBufArray[index++] = waterVertexPos.getX();
            vertBufArray[index++] = waterVertexPos.getY();
            vertBufArray[index++] = waterVertexPos.getZ();
        }
    }
```

The for loop changes the yposition of each vertex using the above formula:

```
float yPos = (float) (A* Math.cos((w * (y) + w *   (x)) + wt* t+ FI));
```

The information for the Formula:

Amplitude of these waves (A): half of the length between wave crest to trough;

Wavelength (L): distance between two wave crests; 
Spatial angular frequency (w): direction of spatial anglular frequency is the same 
with the wave diffuse direction, and the quantity is 
relative with the wavelength L: |w|=2*PI/L;

Speed of waves (s): distance of the waves moved in one second;

Temporal angular frequency (wt): wt=S*2*PI/L;

Direction of waves (D): the direction of the wave crests.

Initiatory phase (FI): the initiatory phase of waves;

EDIT:

using this formula gives me the following result:
[image]

Source:

http://lnu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:205412/FULLTEXT01

Comment: post more of your code... I don't think this deserves a down vote but show us more of your work

Comment: What are the variables? Please explain a little more instead of expecting others to browse through a pretty big pdf file.

Comment: The question is very unclear. What are those numbers? I assume, some of those are really vectors / matrices? Where is a missing bracket?

Comment: Seems to be it is correct. But you can try to write a code using this.

Comment: your original formula has unbalanced parenthesis. And what does `w *（x，y)` mean? If (x,y) is a vector, how do you take cosine of a vector? If (x,y) is a complex number, `Math.cos` does not work with complex numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w` is a vector, so you need two numbers `wx` and `wy`:

```
float yPos = A*Math.cos(wx*x + wy*y + wt*t+ FI);
```

Otherwise, all should be fine, just be sure to expand all vector / matrix expressions into arithmetic operations when you encounter those.